# My GUI app does not show up when I run the program

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a Mac OS (Version: 12.6.5) and I downloaded javaFX to work on GUI applications. I'm using Eclipse to run my program and when I do, a folder icon shows up on my dock, but nothing happens. Even when I click on it, nothing happens nor show up. How can I make the windows show up on my screen?

This is a simple code that I tried running, but it didn't work:

'''

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("My First App");
        stage.show();
    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

'''

Comment: `stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(), 200, 200));` write this before the `stage.show();` for more info https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: The code runs correctly rom the command line.